# property 'reason' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using `// @ts-check` in a JavaScript file. TypeScript complains on this line (in vscode):

```js
myAbortController.signal.addEventListener("abort", (evt) => console.log(evt.target.reason));
```

Can I make TypeScript accept this in the JavaScript file?

Comment: Where are you getting `reason` from? The [`abort` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/abort_event) raises a generic [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) whose `target` property is an [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) which does not have any properties.

Comment: If you have some custom properties on `evt.target`, you'll need to cast before accessing them since TS does not know about them; it assumes `evt` is `EventTarget | null`.

Comment: @DM `reason` is just the reason I give to `AbortController.abort(reason)`. It shows up in the "abort" event handler on `event.target.reason`. It works. Except for TypeScript that complains.

Comment: @DM Chrome seems to know, but TypeScript does not know. And I do not know how to cast this in a JavaScript file. Is it possible? (I am using `// @ts-check` in this JavaScript file.)

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd cast that in JS to satisfy `@ts-check` since the `EventTarget` type it will use is part of [lib.dom.d.ts](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.eventtarget.html). The [`@ts-check` docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html) say you can add `// @ts-ignore` to explicitly ignore errors on a line. That might be the route I'd go here.

Comment: @DM Oh, thanks. That was what I was looking for. (And it is mentioned for beginners here: https://dev.to/evaldasburlingis/typescript-for-beginners-how-to-ignore-code-4han )